# GraphicRaycaster performance OnClick

Tags: unity, performance, gui, input, raycasting

Let's say I have two Canvases: `BackgroundCanvas` and `UICanvas`.

Now, on `BackgroundCanvas` I have multiple moving, not clickable objects so I removed the `GraphicRaycaster` (+ 69 to performance).

On the `UICanvas`, all the objects are on the `UI` layer.
I also have some additional layers somewhere else.

Now, if I change the `GraphicRaycaster`'s (on `UICanvas`) blocking mask to `UI` only, would it improve performance if there are other objects on the `Default` and other layers? Or would it still ray all these objects on other layers?

How does this really work? I'm asking cause I don't see any performance impact while switching these Blocking Masks, but after disabling the entire component - I do (but the input is not working ;S).

Answer (score 2):

No, changing the blocking mask won't improve performance. For example, even if you set the blocking mask to `Nothing` in your `UICanvas`, the calls will be triggerd the same. Same goes if the children objects are inactive.

One quick way to improve performance by reducing calls is to disable the `Raycast Target` bool in all the children objects that shouldn't be checked by the raycaster.